# How do I convert a negative f32 value to binary string and back again

Tags: rust

I have a `vec<f32>` of signed floats. I want to be able to convert the values, both positive and negative, to a single binary string and then convert them back to the original vec values.

**Edit: Comment on the Accepted Answer**

As explained in the accepted answer, the trick is to use the `f32::to_bits` and `f32::from_bits` methods.

The `f32::to_bits` converts an f32 value, both positive and negative, to a u32 value. The `f32::from_bits` converts that u32 value back into the original signed f32 value. In other words, the u32 value determines both the f32 value and its sign.

This was just what I needed because it is straightforward to format a u32 values into a binary string. Reversing this process recovers the original f32 value including its sign.

Below is the code I ended up with.

```
fn get_binary_from_values(values: &[f32]) -> String {
    let mut bin = String::with_capacity(values.len() * 32);
    values.iter().for_each(|v| {
        bin.push_str(&format!("{:032b}", v.to_bits()));
    });
    bin
}

fn get_values_from_binary(bin: &str) -> Vec<f32> {
    (0..bin.len() / 32)
        .map(|i| {
            let start = i * 32;
            let end = start + 32;
            f32::from_bits(u32::from_str_radix(&bin[start..end], 2).unwrap())
        })
        .collect()
}

fn main() {
    let values = vec![0f32, 1f32, f32::MAX, f32::MIN];
    let s = get_binary_from_values(&values);
    let values2 = get_values_from_binary(&s);
    assert_eq!(values, values2);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=466389089b8cec2f5996cf968efcd51c)

Comment: You probably want to use [`f32::to_bits`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.f32.html#method.to_bits) to get the binary representation, instead of `as` which will truncate the float into an integer value.

Comment: Then read as `u32` and use `f32::from_bits` to go the other way.

Comment: Have you considered using serde? serde_bin can convert any serializable type (which include, I think `Vec<f32>`) into a binary blob, and back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `to_bits`/`from_bits` and dump to the string with whatever format you may find useful, for example:

```rust
fn get_binary_from_values(values: &[f32]) -> String {
    let bits: Vec<_> = values.iter().map(|v| v.to_bits().to_string()).collect();
    bits.join(";")
}

fn get_values_from_binary(bin: &str) -> Vec<f32> {
    bin.split(";")
        .map(|bits| f32::from_bits(bits.parse().unwrap()))
        .collect()
}

fn main() {
    let values = vec![0f32, 1f32, f32::MAX, f32::MIN];
    let s = get_binary_from_values(&values);
    let values2 = get_values_from_binary(&s);
    assert_eq!(values, values2);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2afed4ac44a6fd459c5d09086a32fbf5)

Comment: Just be sure to watch out for endian issues.